# Non-conductive pads in datasheet?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, microsd

I'm designing a device which has a [DM3CS-SF microSD connector](http://www.hirose.co.jp/cataloge_hp/e60900232.pdf) and in the recommended land-pattern for the datasheet they have areas labeled as "Non-conducting traces". What am I suppose to do with these areas? Are these keep-out areas where I shouldn't route anything on the same layer, or do I need to provide a trace with solder mask on them (so that they can't get soldered/electrically connected to the connector)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They actually say *"No conducting traces"*. It means that metal parts of the connector (may) touch the PCB in those areas, and conductive traces may be shorted by them.

In practice it means no routing there, not even with a solder resist over the traces. Solder resist does not guarantee electrical insulation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I should avoid routing anything here, even if there's going to be solder mask over my traces?

Comment: @helloworld922 - yes, and that's a good point. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @helloworld922 - Relying on the solder mask is very risky. Even if it works initially, what if your device is in a high-vibration environment? It could abrade through the solder-mask over time.